# How do you find an data-auto-id

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Our Devs are using data-auto-id within the latest project

1. makes my scripting hard and
2. selenium does not recognise it as an ID unfortunately.

Can anyone tell me how in my POM i can identify data-auto-id within C#/.NET without a huge code overhead.

Currently I am writing my POM as per below, so if we can stick to this format that would be great.

```
public IWebElement PWReset { get { return _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("CSS Data here, too long to post")); } }
```

HTML for this example

```
<div data-auto-id="Password_Reset" class="StyledForgotPasswordLabel-sc-gxihsg jmrJqH">Forgotten your password?</div>
```

Code to Guys Suggestion

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
public IWebElement PWReset { get { return _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-auto-id='Password_Reset']")); } }
```

Error being produced is as follows:
*OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[data-auto-id='Password_Reset']"} (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)'*

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML that uses the "data-auto-id"? Does this mean the `id` attribute is being auto generated, or are they using the `data-auto-id` custom HTML 5 attribute?

Comment: Also, you have a C# syntax error in the code you posted. If this is your actual C# code, then your solution should not even build in Visual Studio. This would need to be corrected first.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It builds every time and all my other tests build, run, pass/fail on genuine reasons too.

As for the auto_id yes, theyre being auto generated.

Comment: Ok. Can you correct the syntax error in your question then? I think it is misleading people.

Comment: @GregBurghardt All done, not sure who edited it originally to format it but they dropped the }}

Comment: In order for us to answer your question though, we need to see some of the HTML you are trying to find, and some of the HTML above and below it? Also, are you getting an error when the test runs, and if so what is the error? Otherwise we cannot answer your question.

Comment: The error i get with the amended code is: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[data-auto-id='Password_Reset']"} (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)' and as for the code surrounding my Auto ID this is now above for you.

Comment: Please add this to your question. This is critical information, and it is difficult to read in the comments.

Comment: Is your element in an IFRAME?

Comment: Is this a angular/react or vue.js front-end website ?

Answer (score 1):

The below expression is not ID its a cssSelector syntax

```
#Password_Reset > div > div
```

Either use `By.CssSelector` instead of `By.Id`

or if Password_Reset is your id you can use xpath as:

```
By.Xpath("//*[@id='Password_Reset']/div/div")
```

Add HTML code for exact locator

Comment: Or CSS selector `#Password_Reset > div > div`

Comment: As for the above, unfortunately our XPATH has "app" in them all, so VS things thats all I actually want and doesnt include the rest of the XPATH text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CssSelector` to locate by attribute

```
_driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-auto-id='Password_Reset']"));
```

You might need to use wait:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
return wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("[data-auto-id='Password_Reset']")));
```

Comment: Unfortunately no such luck, I get the following: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: 'no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[data-auto-id='Password_Reset']"}
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.90)'

Comment: No such luck again, waited 10 seconds to be sure and same error.

Comment: Guy you have provided id cssselector .. he needs to traverse a more div .. see his attempt in his question ... CalAtk if you want a proper answer add html of the passwords id and div you are targetting

Comment: @CalAtk: Can you update your question with the code you tried when implementing Guy's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below xPath

```
//div[@data-auto-id='Password_Reset']
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be alot more simpple than we think, using the following does/will work.

```
public IWebElement SubmitDetails { get { return _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("[data-auto-id='login_button_submit'")); } }
```